# How to access element in JSON and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I access something like this with Javascript and Jquery?

```
"condition" : [{"conditionId":["3000"],"conditionDisplayName":["Used"]}]
```

(this is just an excerpt)

I tried using item.condition and I got:
 `[{"conditionId":["3000"],"conditionDisplayName":["Used"]}]` as a result.

How do I get the `conditionDisplayName`?

I've also tried using : `item.condition.conditionDisplayName` but it doesn't work nor does `item.condition[1]`

Comment: Try  item.condition[0].conditionDisplayName

Comment: `item.condition[1]` - close, but array indices in javascript start at `0` not `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there but your `condition` is an array with one object so you need to use the array notation to access it:

```
var displayName = item.condition[0].conditionDisplayName;
```

If there could be more than one object in the array, you can use a loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<item.condition.length; i++) {
    console.log( item.condition[i].conditionDisplayName );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`condition` is an array, as is `conditionDisplayName`, so you will need to access their members using an index. For example, to get the first displayName of the first condition you would do:

```
var displayName = item.condition[0].conditionDisplayName[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array index to get the object

```
var displayName = obj.condition[0].conditionDisplayName;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should try:

```
item.condition[0].conditionDisplayName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [{"conditionId":["3000"],"conditionDisplayName":["Used"]}]

// Not right - show ["Used"]
console.log(array[0].conditionDisplayName);

// Right - show "Used"
console.log(array[0].conditionDisplayName[0]);
```

You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/bs9kx/